# Obtaining account name through boto3?

Tags: boto3

Is there a way to obtain current "account name" through boto3? IE, the human readable account name that can be set through AWS account settings, and can be used in place of account number in a few places.

I don't see it in the info printed from `boto3.client('sts').get_caller_identity()`

Answer (score 2):

needs to go through `iam` client

```
def get_account_name() -> str:
  iam_client = boto3.client('iam')
  response = iam_client.list_account_aliases()
  aliases = response.get('AccountAliases', [])
  if aliases:
    return aliases[0]
  else:
    return ''
```

Answer (score 1):

Its late but might be helpful for future.
If you are using organization service then using below code you can fetch **Account Name**.

```
org = boto3.client('organizations')
account_name = org.describe_account(AccountId='<account-id>').get('Account')
print(account_name ['Name'])
```

Comment: Note: this seems to require permissions at the org level rather than just the account. I attempted this with administrator permissions on the account I wanted to get the name of (`<account-id>` in the example) but didn't have permission to call describe_account.